# Redirect only home page

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I need to redirect only http://shop.test.com  to  http://www.test.com/fedex-orders/

Just homepage.  Nothing else.  ie  http://shop.test.com/?page=blog should NOT redirect.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
location = / {
    return 301 http://www.test.com/fedex-orders/;
}
```

The use of `=` in [`location`](https://nginx.org/r/location)`= /` specifies that the URL must match `/` exactly, with nothing else preceding or following it.

Answer (score -3):

In case you look for an answer how to solve this in Apache; This would be what you want:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ http://www.test.com/fedex-orders/
```

Comment: getting error on configtest

Comment: That's because this is an Apache configuration directive.

Comment: This ISN'T the correct answer. The question is about nginx, not apache.